# How to display win panel once the item left equal to zero?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to display win panel in the game once itemLeft = 0. But still cant figure out how and what is the error about. Below shows my getScore coding:-

```
public GameObject scoretext;
public GameObject itemlefttext;
public GameObject finalScore;
public static float score = 0;

public GameObject winPanel;

private void Start()
{
    scoretext.GetComponent<Text>().text = "0";
    setscore(0);
}

private void Update()
{
    itemlefttext.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("draggableobject").Length;

    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("draggableobject").Length == 0)
    {
        winPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
}

public void setscore(float scoretoadd)
{
    score += scoretoadd;
    scoretext.GetComponent<Text>().text = score.ToString("F0");
    finalScore.GetComponent<Text>().text = score.ToString("F0");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to implement this.

### With your current code structure:

```
private void Update()
{
itemlefttext.GetComponent<Text>().text = ""+GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("draggableobject").Length;

//itemLeftTxt = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
itemLeftTxt.text = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text;

if (itemLeftTxt.text == "0")
{
    winPanel.SetActive(true);
}
}
```

### Minor Improvement:

```
private void Update()
{
    itemlefttext.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("draggableobject").Length;

    //itemLeftTxt = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    itemLeftTxt.text = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>().text;

    if (GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("draggableobject").Length == 0)
    {
        winPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

If those draggable objects are not spawned on runtime then you can create a public variable and assign a reference to them through the inspector OR

### New way:

```
    public GameObject[] DraggableObjects;
```

Add this to the start function:

```
        DraggableObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("draggableobject");
        itemLeftTxt = gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();
```

You can delete extra line of codes:

### Final Update function:

```
private void Update()
{
    itemlefttext.text = "" + DraggableObjects.Length;

    if (DraggableObjects.Length == 0)
    {
        winPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

### Final Start Function:

```
private void Start()
{
    DraggableObjects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("draggableobject");
    itemLeftTxt = GetComponent<Text>();
}
```

PS: Calling Gameobject.FindGameObjectsWithTag inside the update would be heavy on processor. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hye sir.. I already try the minor improvement, but my winPanel did not appear when the item left = 0...

Comment: What is the logic behind draggable objects? Are you deleting them? because if they are added only then it will never be 0.

Comment: sir.. I already edit my question. It works but why the score in the win panel did not change?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot showing your inspector as well as the gameplay? "Windowed view". 

What is the name of that gameobject? probably you need another Text variable for that gameobject?

Comment: As i see in the question, its probably because you are using SetScore(0). it changes the value of scoreText to 0. 

code is working..

Comment: then sir.. what should i change so that I can get the current marks in the win panel?

Comment: SetScore(0) in the start function is actually causing the issue.

Comment: Where is the logic for counting score? 
And, what gameobject does scoretext variable refer to?

Comment: There is no logic i put in my score or marks. I put the coding in my gamecontroller which namely getScore. I already edit my question with more information...